# Convert list items to defined data type RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark

Actually I'm working in workspace of Apache Spark Python in Databricks of Cloudera. The idea is to read a csv and format each field.

So, the first step was to read the csv:

```
uber = sc.textFile("dbfs:/mnt/uber/201601/pec2/uber_curated.csv")
```

The next step was to convert each line to a list of values:

```
uber_parsed = uber.map(lambda lin:lin.split(","))
print (uber_parsed.first())
```

The result was:

```
[u'B02765', u'2015-05-08 19:05:00', u'B02764', u'262', u'Manhattan',u'Yorkville East']
```

But, now I need to convert each item of the next list of values to next format String, Date, String, Integer, String, String.

```
[[u'B02765', u'2015-05-08 19:05:00', u'B02764', u'262', u'Manhattan', u'Yorkville East'],
[u'B02767', u'2015-05-08 19:05:00', u'B02789', u'400', u'New York', u'Yorkville East']]
```

Somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv` reader. In Spark 1.x you'll need an external dependency ([`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)).

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sqlContext.read.format("csv").schema(StructType([
    StructField("_1", StringType()),
    StructField("_2", TimestampType()),
    StructField("_3", StringType()),
    StructField("_4", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_5", StringType()),
    StructField("_6", StringType()),
])).load("dbfs:/mnt/uber/201601/pec2/uber_curated.csv").rdd
```

or

```
sqlContext.read.format("csv").schema(StructType([
    StructField("_1", StringType()),
    StructField("_2", DateType()),
    StructField("_3", StringType()),
    StructField("_4", IntegerType()),
    StructField("_5", StringType()),
    StructField("_6", StringType()),
])).option("dateFormat", "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").load(
    "dbfs:/mnt/uber/201601/pec2/uber_curated.csv"
).rdd
```

You can replace (`_1`, `_2` ..`_n`) with descriptive field names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but generate this error. 'RDD' object is not callable

Comment: Sorry, extraneous brackets. Should be OK now.

Comment: There is `DateType` and `dateFormat` option and some date formatting functions.